# Cannot append to NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I'm trying to append the file extension to a the stringValue returned by a subclassed NSTextFieldCell

I've tried everything I knew and could find on the internet, but this is just giving me a headache

the method is the following:

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {

    NSMutableString *filename = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [filename appendString:self.stringValue];

    NSString *iconFileName = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"png"];
    NSLog(@"%@", iconFileName);

}
```

The returned value is without the extension though!
I've also tried the following:

```
filename = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@.png", filename];
```

This returns the "filename" string without the ".png"

Similarly:

```
filename = [filename stringByAppendingString: @".png"];
```

returns just the "filename"

The table column where this cell belongs to is bound to an NSObject, and the method that sends the data to the column is the following:

```
- (NSString *) nationString {
    NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    int index = 0;

    if (nationAddress && nationAddress > 0x0) {
        index = [[[[controller database] nationsAddressIndex] valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lli", nationAddress]] intValue];
        Nation *nationality = [[[controller database] nations] objectAtIndex:index];
        [string appendString:[nationality name]];
    }
    else {
        [string appendString:@"---"];
    }

    return string;
}
```

Anyone has any idea why this might be happening, or can suggest any alternatives?
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: `filename = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@.png", filename];` should work, if filename is an NSString.  You appear to have it declared as an NSMutableString which might cause compile problems but still should execute OK.  I suspect you're not displaying your values correctly somehow.

Comment: thanks, I've tried with both NSString and NSMutableString, both behave the same. filename is NSMutableString, as shown in the first block of code, it comes from the value of self.stringValue which is of type NSString, from the subclassed NSTextFieldCell. I'm looking at the values inside the XCode debugger and by dumping them to the NSLog as well. The value I get after `filename = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@.png", filename];` does not include the ".png" part and therefore the rest of my code does not work as it can't find the file since it's missing the extension

Comment: Dump the string with NSLog.  Debuggers often lie.

Comment: "I'm looking at the values inside the XCode debugger and by dumping them to the NSLog as well"

Comment: Use a variable name other than "filename" -- I suspect you've got that `#defined` or some such.

Comment: I already tried this, the results are the same. I don't `#define filename` anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried "cleaning" your project?  You're screwing something up somehow.

Comment: Yes, I have. The same block was working for the previous version of my app, then I started rebuilding it and moved some classes over. I made sure that the project build settings all match, and while everything else works perfectly fine, this one is driving me nuts! Anyway, I think I'll just redo this part so it works differently, thanks for trying to help!

Comment: You sure you don't have a category on NSString that's screwing you up somehow.  Or a heap management bug that's allowing the same storage to be allocated twice?

Comment: Now that some edit brought this question up again. Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: This was a long time ago, I did manage to figure it out by approaching it in a different way. Instead of
`NSMutableString *filename = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; [filename appendString:self.stringValue];`
I ended up doing `NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%i.png", nationID];` so I'm now formatting the filename with a number instead of a string and that works. Still to this day, I have no idea why the original is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just for test. Try to use this code and update here a output values:

```
NSMutableString *filename = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[filename appendString:self.stringValue];
NSLog(@"text1: %@ ;", filename);

filename = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@.png", filename];
filename = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@.png%@", filename, filename];
NSLog(@"text2: %@ ;", filename);
```

Comment: Here's the output from the NSLog: 
`text1: Brazil` 
`text2: Brazil`

Comment: I added  a temp changes. Now output is what?

Answer (score 0):

This should return the complete path with extension:

```
NSString *path =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Default.png"];
NSLog(@"%@", path);
```

So, assuming self.stringValue includes the extension, your method *should* work with this:

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {    
    NSString *iconFileName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.stringValue];
    NSLog(@"%@", iconFileName);
}
```

If it doesn't include the extension, try this:

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {
    NSString *strWithPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", self.stringValue];
    NSString *iconFileName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:strWithPath];
    NSLog(@"%@", iconFileName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. self.stringValue does not include the extension, using your last code block is still not attaching the ".png" extension. I'd normally think that NSLog is not displaying the value correctly for some reason, because it doesn't make sense, but even after trying: `if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:iconFileName]) {  }` it doesn't work. Simply because iconFileName is still missing the extension (the file is definitely there!)

Comment: Show me the `@property` declaration for stringValue (and the instance variable / `@synthesize` if that's there too).

Comment: There is no `@property` declaration for stringValue, I don't override that. `stringValue` is defined by `NSTextFieldCell`

Answer (score 0):

These should work (barring a typo):

```
NSString* filename = @"abc";

NSString* result1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", filename];

NSString* result2 = [filename stringByAppendingString:@".png"];

NSMutableString* result3 = [filename mutableCopy];
[result3 appendString:@".png"];
```

If they don't appear to be working then you have some problem with how you're initializing or displaying your values.

Hint:  Place an `NSLog(@"The answer is %@", resultN);` statement *immediately* after each of the above (with "resultN" changed appropriately) to see what you're getting.  Keep in mind that if you look from a different object you may be looking at different variables.

Comment: If I initialise the filename variable myself with a string it does work. It doesn't work though, when I initialise it with the value of self.stringValue as in my first post. self.stringValue is an NSString that gives me the text in the tableview cell which I subclassed. I did try NSLog after every line, the .png extension is never attached to the filename!

Comment: @ThanosSiopoudis -- You're still not making sense.  Have you tried NSLogging the initial value you get from self.stringValue?

Comment: self.stringValue is of type __NSCFString, contents @"Brazil".